# Jest can't process SVG files imported with an argument

Tags: vue.js, svg, jestjs, babel-jest

With [@nuxtjs/svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/svg) in "vue-svg-loader" mode, SVGs are imported like so:
`import ArrowRight from '~/assets/img/arrow-right.svg?inline'`

But `Jest` has a problem with the "?inline" part:

```
Could not locate module ~/assets/img/arrow-right.svg?inline mapped as:
D:\path\to\project\$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^~\/(.*)$/": "D:\path\to\project\$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

I tried both of the answers given to a [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236895/using-vue-and-jest-to-testing-svg-inline) but in each case I'm getting the same error.

Any suggestion about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone bumping into this issue, solution is [here](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/73#issuecomment-478295746):

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.svg": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*svg)(\\?inline)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ["jest-serializer-vue"],
  testMatch: ["**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  collectCoverageFrom: ["!**/src/__mocks__/**", "**/src/**/*.{js,vue}"]
};
```

The crucial point is the following:

"The line that interests you is this one, `"^@/(.*svg)(\\?inline)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"`. Be careful to add it above the default regex, `"^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"`, order counts here."